# How can I change invoice sequence in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I want to change this format generated by default in odoo , with a custom format from this:

[image]

to this :

```
ING-ENR-YEAR-MONTH
```

How I can do it?

Comment: That's a functional question and has nothing to do with programming. Please ask such questions on the [official Odoo forums](https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. activate the developer mode
2. Go to Settings > Technical > External Identifiers > Sequences
3. Search for the `Customer Invoices` and open the record
4. Change the prefix to `ING-ENR-%(year)s-%(month)s` (see image)

[image]

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, i do it but it still the same result nothing happen

Comment: @Mahmoud, make sure you are updating the correct record of `ir.sequence`